# .NET non-nullable reference type and out parameters

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I modified my `csproj` file to enable null reference types in C#8:

```xml
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

Given the following code:

```cs
private static void Method()
{
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    string value = string.Empty;

    dictionary.TryGetValue("Key", out value);
}
```

The line with `TryGetValue()` gives the warning:

> `CS8600`: Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.

I don't understand why. The signature of `TryGetValue()` is :

```cs
public bool TryGetValue(string key, [MaybeNullWhen(false)] out string value);
```

The code example has only non-nullable references. Why is it getting this error?

Comment: I find a related issue in the Rosalyn GitHub repository :
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/38329

Comment: What if you declare `value` as `string?`?

Comment: @canton7 I jumped to the conclusion and the far more dangerous NRE in the OP's code, so I didn't notice the entire discussion. You have to use `out var` or `out string?`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Indeed, that's what the answers posted yesterday both say. Strictly speaking, there's nothing in the OP's code which will trigger an NRE, though.

Comment: @canton7 `value.Length` if the key is missing will throw

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Indeed it would, but the OP's code doesn't do that. It's true that they *might* write something which assumes that `value` is not `null`, but the actual code in the question does not.

Comment: @Sweeper, I have declared `value` as `string?` for my code is compliance.
@canton7, @PanagiotisKanavos, what is `OP's code`?

Comment: @Orwel OP is the Original Poster -- i.e. you. "OP's code" is your code, the code in your question.

Comment: Yes, if you declare value as string? (and not necessary assign to it something), compiler will keep silent. But I still don't understand the whole idea of non-nullable objects: it makes you to add casts in a lots of places, which defeats the purpose. If you don't develop something from the scratch, and want to keep everything tidy, it is a nightmare to make all the changes. Compiler is not smart enough not to complain about the cases, when you just assigned non-null object. Maybe I will accept it with time, but so far it looks like a code bloat for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation [Attributes for null-state static analysis interpreted by the C# compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis).

> In a nullable enabled context, the compiler performs static analysis of code to determine the null-state of all reference type variables:
>
> - not-null: Static analysis determines that a variable has a non-null value.
> - maybe-null: Static analysis can't determine that a variable is assigned a non-null value.

The static analyzer consider a variable can be :

- nullable
- not nullable
- maybe nullable

When a not nullable variable is decorated with the attribute [MaybeNull](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.maybenullattribute), the static analyser consider the variable is maybe nullable.

```cs
[return: MaybeNull]
static string Find(string key)
{
    return key == "" ? null : key;
}

string value1 = Find("key"); // Warning CS8600 Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.
string? value2 = Find("key"); // No warning
var value3 = Find("key"); // The inferred type is 'string?'
```

The [MaybeNullWhen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.maybenullattribute) attribute is similar, but the static analyser can handle checks based on the result of the method.

```cs
static bool TryGetValue(string key, [MaybeNullWhen(false)] out string value)
{
    if(key == "")
    {
        value = null;
        return false;
    }
    value = "Foo";
    return true;
}

string notnullable;

string value1;
if (TryGetValue("Key", out value1)) // Warning CS8600 Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.
    notnullable = value1;
else
    notnullable = value1; // Warning CS8600 Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.

string? value2;
if (TryGetValue("Key", out value2))
    notnullable = value2;
else
    notnullable = value2; // Warning CS8600 Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.
```

I agree, that makes no sense in this examples. But with a generic method, you can specify a non nullable type while the method can return/set null:

```cs
[return: MaybeNull]
static T Find<T>(string key);
static bool TryGetValue<T>(string key, [MaybeNullWhen(false)] out T value)
```

Answer (score 18):

If `"Key"` isn't found in the dictionary, then a value of `null` will be assigned to the `value` variable. However you've declared `value` as `string`, meaning that it shouldn't contain `null`. Therefore the compiler is giving you a warning.

The fact that you've initially assigned `string.Empty` to `value` doesn't matter - that will always get overwritten by `TryGetValue` (and you should get another warning which says that).

You should declare `value` as a `string?`, to indicate that its value might be `null`.

Note that the compiler's pretty smart. If you write:

```
if (!dictionary.TryGetValue("Key", out string? value))
{
    value = string.Empty;
}
```

then the compiler knows that `value` cannot be `null`, and it won't complain if you then try and call methods on it.

Comment: TryGetValue can ouput null, but the signature says 'NO'. Then why I have a error when the signature says 'no null can output'. I think it's a rosalyn's bug.

Comment: @Orwel What do you mean, "*but the signature says 'NO'*"? The signature of `TryGetValue` contains `[MaybeNullWhen(false)]`, which means that `value` needs to be nullable. This is **not** a Roslyn bug.

Comment: `public bool TryGetValue(string key, [MaybeNullWhen(false)] out string value);`, where `value` can't be null.

Comment: @Orwel I don't follow. You need to pass a `string?`, because `value` might be assigned the value `null`. That's what `MaybeNullWhen` means.

Answer (score 3):

canton7's answer is correct (+1).
This is not an explanation but a workaround:
You could add an extension method to `Dictionary<TVey, TValue>` like this:

```
public static bool TryGetValue<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key, TValue @default, out TValue @value) where TKey : notnull
{
    var result = dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var val);
    @value = result ? val : @default;
    return result;
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
private static void Method()
{
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    /// populate dictionary here...

    dictionary.TryGetValue("Key", string.Empty, out var value);
}
```

This should enable you to keep `value` as a non-nullable string.

Comment: This could be reduced to `return TryGetValue(key,out var val)?val:@default` or even inlined `var resultValue=TryGetValue(key,out var val)?val:string.Empty`

Comment: Note that this straight-up doesn't compile - you can't declare `TValue?` without putting a generic type constraint of `class` or `struct`. You also need a `notnull` constraint on `TKey`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This method returns a `bool`, not the actual value. It's true that you could write a different method which returns `TValue`, but that's not what this does.

Comment: @canton7 This is an untested example - but I've edited my answer according to panagiotis's comment and to yours - it should be fine now.

Comment: It's well worth testing your answers -- https://sharplab.io is good. It still compiles with a warning.

Comment: @canton7 I agree, I just didn't know sharplab supports c# 8... Can't see compiler warnings there, anyway, and I don't have vs 2019 to test with.

Comment: [See here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQGADAAQY4oDchAxAHYCuANswIbDMykz0deEMAZnI4k5LKQDCpAN6FSi8iIrjgECM1IAVKAE8A4jAAuANTbNGMADzaA0jD0AaHecswAfAApjACwCWAM6kACL+YMb+EHz6tg7OrhZWHqQAJuGR0Wz6LvaOpADWjrluVuQYqTAAZmwsxi4QjMaJ7uUAbkkwAJQKSvIESoMtZR3MNANDih1QpLCBdaQAvGkZUTF6AHS6hialMF5FCY3No13jk4oYGKNly3MLAPyko6Qg5ZU1decXGADsszB5sxjN9FABfQhgoA==). The warning is on the bottom right. You need `where TKey : notnull`.